# Hashids PHP namespace issue : Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1

Tags: php, hash, character, ascii, hashids

I want to use [hashids](http://www.hashids.org/php/) with PHP.
However, my web host (000webhost.com) has an older version of PHP installed, and it gives an error :

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1
```

in this line :

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('hash_seed');
```

How can I work this around? I cannot change any PHP configuration. Any suggestions ?

Comment: "older php" says it all - your version of PHP doesn't support namespaces. There is NO workaround. Don't use namespaces, or don't use webhosts that only offer obsolete PHP installs.

Comment: No way to use hashids without namespaces ?

Comment: Probably, but that depends entirely on how that library's written. Go through, rip out all the namespace references, and see what happens. Don't be surprised if it ends up being totally broken, though.